could Eisenstein polynomial admit multiple root?
That is the question !
In a local field could an Eisenstein polynomial admit a mutiple root ?
A point in the construction of Lubin-tate extension seems to need only simple roots.
Thank you

In characteristic $0$ (where Lubin-Tate theory lives), irreducible polynomials are separable (see e.g. here), so an Eisenstein polynomial cannot have roots of multiplicity $>1$.
In positive characteristic, there are counterexamples, e.g. let the field be $\mathbb F_p((t))$ and take the Eisenstein polynomial $X^p - t$ ($t$ is the uniformizer here).

What you say is curious because i never read anything about a characteristic $0$ for local class field theory..

You're right, sorry. Edited that, the rest is correct I think ...?
